# after updating to ubuntu 15.04, the mouse pointer disappears over the gnome sidebar and top menus

Tags: gnome, mouse, launcher, 15.04

After i made this update, the mouse cursor disappears when its over the launcher menu and the top right menu in gnome. I already tried several things given in other questions/answers but nothing seems to correct this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What solutions have you tried? are you using gnome shell?

Comment: I would say it's a bug, wait for another patch? Have you reported it?`

Comment: I did not report it. It happened before with other previous updates. Is there a way to reset the mouser pointer configurations?

Comment: I have the same problem. $ umane -a Linux regis-PC 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux $ cat /etc/issue Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS \n \l

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.

And, finally, I found this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-346/+bug/1440012

So, I think maybe you have installed the nvidia-346 driver?

If you did install nvidia-346 driver, you can downgrade to nvidia-331 or upgrade to nvidia349 to avoid this issue.

fearlessly install driver 349 :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mamarley/nvidia  
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia349
```

or

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

then
goto additional drivers and select driver 349.16

Comment: No.  lshw -c video | grep 'configuration'
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       configuration: latency=0

Answer (score 0):

just update your system by using

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then go to system settings and go to Software & Updates and then go to Additional drivers tab, then choose correct drivers for your graphics. It will fix your problem

Comment: apt-get update doesn't install any new upgrades, it just refershes your source list. to actually install them use apt-get dist-upgrade

Comment: The problem appeared after updating. Making a second update did not made any effect because there is no current more updates to do.